# How to get the proper dimensions of the scene

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I noticed the dimensions of the screen are wrong. I am in portrait mode and if I print the width and the height of my scene, they are 1024x768. How do I get proper dimensions? I did find some articles about that in Objective-C and tried to figure out how to do it in Swift but have no idea how because I am a beginner in Swift and programming.

Is there any straightforward approach to solving this?

Comment: The size of the scene is not necessarily the size of the screen.

Comment: Really? How do I access the size of the screen then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.view.bounds` to get the size of the screen (assuming your view is fullscreen)

The view shows a portion of your scene. You can move the view around the scene to scroll your game. Therefore the scene dimensions are different than the screen dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

UISceen.mainScreen().bounds will always give you dimensions of the screen in its current orientation. Self.view.bounds will give you the size of the view controller you are working in, which in many cases will be the same.